# Como fazer animação de mudança de vídeos com clique do mouse

Tags: javascript, css, animação

Estou com uma dúvida, não sei nem como pesquisar o que eu quero.

A ideia seria clicar na imagem do Vídeo 1 e o Vídeo e o Titulo mudassem sem sair da página, assim pro 2 e 3. Tomei uma surra em uns códigos mas esse na verdade não sei nem como pesquisar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Provavelmente o que procura e uma *Single Page Application* que muda dinamicamente o video sem ter de recarregar a pagina. Umas das frameworks usadas para produzir SPAs e o [tag:AngularJs]

Comment: você já usa jQuery ou outra frame em JS, como Angular? Ou apenas está trabalhando com css/js puro? Tem alguma restrição de usar algum deles?

Comment: No click do video você pode alterar o src do video para o video que voce precisa e colocar o titulo também.

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer isto da seguinte maneira:

```js
function mostraDiv(num) {
    document.getElementById('div1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div3').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('div'+num).style.display='block';
}
```

```css
.hiddenEl{display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="sidebarContainer">
    <button class="imagens" onclick="mostraDiv('1')">Mostra Div 1</button>
    <button class="imagens" onclick="mostraDiv('2')">Mostra Div 2</button>
    <button class="imagens" onclick="mostraDiv('3')">Mostra Div 3</button>
</div>

<div class="mainContainer">
    <div id="div1">Sou a div1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="hiddenEl">Sou a div2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="hiddenEl">Sou a div3</div>
</div>
```

Depois basta fazeres as modificações à tua medida, trocando os botões por `divs` e inserindo imagens dentro delas como *thumbnails de preview* do vídeo que o usuário irá ver, ao clicar no botão/imagem pretendida e também popular as `divs` com o conteúdo (títulos, vídeos etc).

Eu criei [aqui um exemplo no **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/src_code/ezm70m9s/) simples mas bem elaborado de como isto irá funcionar com os respetivos títulos e vídeos para cada botão, para teres uma ideia.